# Web scraping PySpark selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to do web scraping and download a few reports from the web automatically in synapse analytics using PySpark. I researched using selenium python for this and realised that we need to install chrome driver and install selenium packages.  If I install chrome driver on my machine, does that mean that my machine needs to be up and running at the time of running the script?

How do we get it running automatically without additional infrastructure?
Please advise.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Yes, your machine needs to be up and running to run Selenium scripts, but isn't that the case with every other type of script as well?

Comment: Hi @M B, thanks for the reply. What I mean is after I create this web scraping script using python in Azure Synapse analytics and if I want to schedule this job to trigger automatically at say 4am, do we need to keep my machine up and running at that time so that it opens the browser instance and perform the necessary steps to download the report?

Comment: Hi @M B is there any other way to perform web scraping without having the system up and running at the time of running the script?

Comment: I still don't get how you plan to run a build on a machine that isn't up and running?

Comment: @M B in the cloud where my local machine need not be up and running

Comment: So you will be, for example, using an Azure VM? In that case, there is no dependency with your local machine, correct? So you can have the VM running, and download the report at 4AM as scheduled without your local machine having any part in it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this case occurs, when data is injected using javascript dynamically.
One solution could be is render the HTML + javascript using requests_html.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
session.get("https://yoururl.com")
response.html.render()
content = response.html.html
print(content)
```

Note: In this case, there is no need for PySpark.

Comment: I need to be able to use Pyspark as that's the environment we have got.  Is it possible to run script in Pyspark with out the machine up and running?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).